# How can I count rows with datetime64[ns] data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with columns that contain data in the datetime64[ns] format.
In this columns, I would like to count all rows, which have a date.
In a second step I would like to count all entries grouped by year or month.
The dataframe would look like this:

```
    date1       date2       date3
1   2019-08-15  2019-08-15  NaT
2   2019-08-29  2019-09-03  2019-10-15
3   2019-09-11  2019-09-11  NaT
4   2020-02-17  2020-02-17  NaT
5   2020-02-24  2020-02-24  2020-03-08
```

Using a simple `.sum` function does not work as `DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation sum`
Do I have to change the date to string format? Or how can I count datetime64[ns] data? Do I need to set the date as index and the using `.resample`?

The ideal outcome would be three dataframe something like this, a)total numbers, b)by year, c)by month:

```
    date1       date2       date3
0   5           5           2

    year   date1       date2       date3
0   2019   3           3           1
1   2020   2           2           1

    month  date1       date2       date3
0   01     NaN         NaN         NaN
1   02     2           2           NaN
2   03     NaN         NaN         1
3   04     NaN         NaN         NaN
4   05     NaN         NaN         NaN
5   06     NaN         NaN         NaN
6   07     NaN         NaN         NaN
7   08     2           1           NaN 
8   09     1           2           NaN
9   10     NaN         NaN         1
10  11     NaN         NaN         NaN
11  12     NaN         NaN         NaN


Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

---

```
df1 = df.resample('MS', on='date').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
        date  count
0 2019-07-01      1
1 2019-08-01      2
2 2019-09-01      0
3 2019-10-01      0
4 2019-11-01      0
5 2019-12-01      0
6 2020-01-01      0
7 2020-02-01      2


df2 = df.resample('Y', on='date').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
        date  count
0 2019-12-31      3
1 2020-12-31      2
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
        date1       date2       date3  col1
1  2019-08-15  2019-08-15         NaT     4
2  2019-08-29  2019-09-03  2019-10-15     5
3  2019-09-11  2019-09-11         NaT     1
4  2020-02-17  2020-02-17         NaT     0
5  2020-02-24  2020-02-24  2020-03-08     3
```

First convert columns to datetimes and if some another columns use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
cols = ['date1','date2','date3']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df0 = df.select_dtypes('datetime')
print (df0)
       date1      date2      date3
1 2019-08-15 2019-08-15        NaT
2 2019-08-29 2019-09-03 2019-10-15
3 2019-09-11 2019-09-11        NaT
4 2020-02-17 2020-02-17        NaT
5 2020-02-24 2020-02-24 2020-03-08
```

Then use [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for get number of non missing values, convert to one colun DataFrame and transpose for one row DataFrame:

```
df1 = df0.count().to_frame().T
print (df1)
   date1  date2  date3
0      5      5      2
```

For years and months is used [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df2 = df0.apply(lambda x: x.dt.year.value_counts())
print (df2)
    date1  date2  date3
1     NaN    NaN    NaN
2     2.0    2.0    NaN
3     NaN    NaN    1.0
4     NaN    NaN    NaN
5     NaN    NaN    NaN
6     NaN    NaN    NaN
7     NaN    NaN    NaN
8     2.0    1.0    NaN
9     1.0    2.0    NaN
10    NaN    NaN    1.0
11    NaN    NaN    NaN
12    NaN    NaN    NaN

df2 = df0.apply(lambda x: x.dt.month.value_counts()).reindex(range(1,13))
print (df2)
    date1  date2  date3
1     NaN    NaN    NaN
2     2.0    2.0    NaN
3     NaN    NaN    1.0
4     NaN    NaN    NaN
5     NaN    NaN    NaN
6     NaN    NaN    NaN
7     NaN    NaN    NaN
8     2.0    1.0    NaN
9     1.0    2.0    NaN
10    NaN    NaN    1.0
11    NaN    NaN    NaN
12    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: many thanks for the swift reply. Your suggested codes work very well. I also have dates from 2020 in the dataset. I will also modify the example dataset. Your approach gives values grouped by each year and month, which I also need. What would be the easiest approach to summarize over all years?

Comment: @Mikele - Not sure if understand, my code working also with changed data.

Comment: It does work. I just wanted to know if it is possible in the second approach using `dt.year.value_counts())` to add the values for each year? In the first approach, the easiest would be to sum the 'count' column. However, I prefer the second approach as I have a dataframe with several columns and would like to avoid introducing an extra column for each column. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Mikele - I add EDIT to answer, but not 100% sure if need exactly this.

Comment: many thanks for your efforts. I have modified the example dataset. I would like to have for each colum: total number of rows with ANY date, rows with a certain year and rows with a certain month. Month and Year was perefectly answered by you. I was just wondering if there is an easy apporach that would count all rows with any date.

Comment: @Mikele - Thank you for edited data, can you add expected output DataFrame to question from sample data?

Comment: Thanks for you patience. I added an expected ouput dataframe

Comment: Great. Many thanks for your help and time! You are my hero of the day!